# I'm trying to read a line from a file in c and dynamically allocate memory but the result is always bad

Tags: c, file, memory, dynamic, allocation

```
char * readline(FILE *fp, char *buffer) {
  char ch;
  int i = 0, buff_len = 0;

  buffer = malloc(buff_len);

  while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    ++buff_len;
    buffer = realloc(buffer, buff_len);

    buffer[i] = ch;

    ++i;
  }

  return buffer;
}
```

I'm trying to allocate the memory directly after reading a character.

Comment: What would be the reason to pass `buffer` as an argument and instantly overwrite it? Why not make it a local variable? Format your code properly. (there is an `edit` link under your text).

Comment: And why not allocate at least `nchar=64;` for `buffer` and keep a charcount and when `charcount + 1 == nchar` then `realloc (buffer, nchar * 2); nchar *=2;`?

Comment: Okay, this is definitely the kind of code I don't want my CPU to run...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several subtleties in passing a pointer to a function to allocate, fill and return. The most important to understand is that when passing a pointer to a function, the function receives a *copy* of that pointer with a new and separate address. If you then allocate space in the function for the pointer, you *must* return the address of the pointer to the caller (`main()` here) or the caller will have no way to access the values you have stored in your newly allocated block of memory.

To overcome this problem, and be able to pass a pointer to a function for allocation and filling, *without* having to utilize the return, you must pass the *address* of the pointer to the function, i.e.:

```
char *readline (FILE *fp, char **buffer)
```

Otherwise, as discussed in the comments and above, there is no reason to pass the pointer to buffer to the function. You can simply declare `buffer` local to the function, dynamically allocate space for it, and return the starting address to the new block of memory.

There is nothing wrong with doing it either way, it really boils down to what you need, but you want to be clear on what you are passing to your function and why. The following is a short example passing the address of your pointer to `readline` and allowing the function to allocate/fill each line without needing to utilize the return. Now it never hurts to return a pointer to your line in this case. It provides a way of determining success/failure and the flexibility to assign the return if you desire:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NCHAR 64

char *readline (FILE *fp, char **buffer);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t idx = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (readline (fp, &line)) {  /* read each line in 'fp' */
        printf (" line[%2zu] : %s\n", idx++, line);
        free (line);
        line = NULL;
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    return  0;
}

/* read line from 'fp' allocate *buffer NCHAR in size
 * realloc as necessary. Returns a pointer to *buffer
 * on success, NULL otherwise.
 */
char *readline (FILE *fp, char **buffer) 
{
    int ch;
    size_t buflen = 0, nchar = NCHAR;

    *buffer = malloc (nchar);    /* allocate buffer nchar in length */
    if (!*buffer) {
        fprintf (stderr, "readline() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) 
    {
        (*buffer)[buflen++] = ch;

        if (buflen + 1 >= nchar) {  /* realloc */
            char *tmp = realloc (*buffer, nchar * 2);
            if (!tmp) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc failed, "
                                "returning partial buffer.\n");
                (*buffer)[buflen] = 0;
                return *buffer;
            }
            *buffer = tmp;
            nchar *= 2;
        }
    }
    (*buffer)[buflen] = 0;           /* nul-terminate */

    if (buflen == 0 && ch == EOF) {  /* return NULL if nothing read */
        free (*buffer);
        *buffer = NULL;
    }

    return *buffer;
}
```

**Input**

```
$ cat ../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/readline ../dat/captnjack.txt
 line[ 0] : This is a tale
 line[ 1] : Of Captain Jack Sparrow
 line[ 2] : A Pirate So Brave
 line[ 3] : On the Seven Seas.
```

**Note**

You really do not want to allocate for every character. `malloc` is a relatively expensive operation. It makes far more sense to allocate some reasonably anticipated number of characters for each line and then `realloc` if you reach that limit than it does to `realloc` for every character. If you are concerned with only allocating exactly the amount needed to hold the string, then allocate as described, and do one final `realloc` for `strlen(buf) + 1` characters at the end.

Further, allocating in this manner, you can always set `#define NCHAR 1` and force the allocation to start and `1-char` if you like.

**Memory Leak/Error Check**

In any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 responsibilites regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) always preserves a pointer to the starting address for the block of memory so, (2) it can be freed when it is no longer needed. It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory and to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated. For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are so many subtle ways to misuse a block of memory that can cause real problems, there is no excuse not to do it. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use. Just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/readline ../dat/captnjack.txt
==16460== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16460== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16460== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16460== Command: ./bin/readline ../dat/captnjack.txt
==16460==
 line[ 0] : This is a tale
 line[ 1] : Of Captain Jack Sparrow
 line[ 2] : A Pirate So Brave
 line[ 3] : On the Seven Seas.
==16460==
==16460== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16460==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16460==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 888 bytes allocated
==16460==
==16460== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16460==
==16460== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16460== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

You should see `All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible` and `ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts` every time.

**note:** updated to reflect comment on return and type for `ch` and to fix potential memory leak when returning `NULL` from `readline` on `EOF`.

Comment: I would too, but I was thinking about it from a test standpoint and explaining a test for an empty string or simply `NULL`. It's worth a note.

Comment: @chux - worth more than a note -- edited and changed. But there was no memory leak when `buflen == 0`, `line` was freed in `main` regardless.

Comment: Thanks. Always appreciated.

Comment: An FYI about `if (ch == EOF) {... *buffer = NULL`.  When the last "line" in a file does not end with a `'\n'`, there are various approaches.  This code  returns `NULL` losing the last characters.  An `fgets()` like functionality when `ch == EOF` is to return `NULL` if 1) an error occurred or 2) nothing was read, else return the string of the last characters read.

Comment: Why don't we just do `if (!buflen && ch == EOF)` for the final check. That would solve the problem.

Comment: [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34233853/im-trying-to-read-a-line-from-a-file-in-c-and-dynamically-allocate-memory-but-t/34234475?noredirect=1#comment82043033_34234475) would well catch the case of the last "line" that lacks a `'\n'`.  What would you want to happen if the `ch == EOF` was due to a rare input error?  E.g. `ferror()` is true, but not `feof()`.  On error,  `fgets()` return `NULL` even if some characters were read and the buffer is left "array contents are
indeterminate".

Comment: Hmm... that one flew under my RADAR. According to `man fgetc` it will *"return ... EOF on end of file **or error**."* So doesn't `EOF` cover the stream error as well?

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `EOF` on 3 cases:  1) end-of-file indicator is set 2) stream is at end-of-file 3) a read error occurs.  Notice the asymmetry.  It does not return `EOF` if the _error indicator_ is set.  Of course the source of the error may be persistent or isolated and another read error may occur.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, you are saying check both to determine if the EOF was triggered by stream error rather than `EOF` alone. But that would generate `EOF` anyway. So to make use of `ferror` wouldn't we also want to split the check of `EOF` and `ferror` in order to report whether the `EOF` was due to stream error? If we are not making a distinction, then is there any drawback to just checking `EOF`? Or if the case is `ferror`, but no `EOF` wouldn't we need the check in the loop?

Answer (score 3):

Code never makes the allocated buffer a string by appending a null character nor does it allocate space for it.

```
char * readline(FILE *fp, char *buffer) {
  int ch;
  int i = 0;
  size_t buff_len = 0;

  buffer = malloc(buff_len + 1);
  if (!buffer) return NULL;  // Out of memory

  while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    buff_len++;
    void *tmp = realloc(buffer, buff_len + 1);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
      free(buffer);
      return NULL; // Out of memory
    }
    buffer = tmp;

    buffer[i] = (char) ch;
    i++;
  }
  buffer[i] = '\0';

  // Detect end
  if (ch == EOF && (i == 0 || ferror(fp))) {
    free(buffer);
    return NULL;
  }
  return buffer;
}
```

Note:
Reallocating on each iteration is a bit wasteful.
Input value of `buffer` is never used.  Perhaps redesign OP's function.
`ch` should be `int` to properly distinguish `char from`EOF`.

Comment: @Sam `readline()` above reads 1 line from a file and returns.  Add detail to your [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34233853/im-trying-to-read-a-line-from-a-file-in-c-and-dynamically-allocate-memory-but-t/34233913?noredirect=1#comment82032048_34233913).

Comment: Well I have a hw. Movies and actors in a line. All together without any space. Some have more than 240 sticked name. Size of it is changing

Comment: @sam To read a file line by line `char *s; while ((s = readline(fp, 0)) != NULL) { fputs(s);  free(s) }`.

Comment: too few arguments to function 'fputs'

Comment: @sam OK, so use `puts(s);`

Comment: @sam Once you get it cleaned-up and working - post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com for a deeper review - you will learn a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by chux, suggested alternative. Example code to display a text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * readline(FILE *fp) {
    char * buffer = malloc(1024);   /* assume longest line < 1023 chars */
    int ch;
    int i = 0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        buffer[i++] = ch;
    if(ch == EOF){                  /* if eof, free buffer, return */
        free(buffer);
        return 0;
    }
    buffer[i++] = 0;                /* add 0 terminator */
    buffer = realloc(buffer, i);
    return buffer;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *fp;
char *pline;
    if(argc < 2)
        return 0;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while(1){
        pline = readline(fp);
        if(pline == 0)
            break;
        printf("%s\n", pline);
        free(pline);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```